# PHPExcel generating corrupted file - ob_end_clean() not working

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I'm trying to generate a **.xlsx** file using **PHPExcel**. The process is generating the file, but when I'm getting to open the file, It says It's corrupted. When I use *Open and Repair*, the file opens and It's ok, but I don't want to repair everytime I generate the file. I tried to use the function `ob_end_clean()` before saving, but It didn't work.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$objSheet1 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$objSheet1->setTitle("sheet1");
$line_value = 1;
foreach($sheet1_data as $line){
    $col = 'A';
    foreach($line as $cell_value){
        $objSheet1->setCellValue($col.$line_value, $cell_value);
        $col++;
    }
    $line_value++;
}

$objSheet2 = $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
$objSheet2->setTitle("sheet2");
$line_value = 1;
foreach($sheet2_data as $line){
    $col = 'A';
    foreach($line as $cell_value){
        $objSheet2->setCellValue($col.$line_value, $cell_value);
        $col++;
    }
    $line_value++;
}

ob_end_clean();
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter ( $objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007' );
$objWriter->save ( get_file_location() );
```

Comment: What is this `$objSheetOperacional` where you're setting cell values when the rest of your code references `$objSheet1` and `$objSheet2`?

Comment: As to why it's not working, no obvious reason at all... are you creating this as a new PHPExcel object, or loading a template?

Comment: I create a new PHPExcel object everytime I call this function.

Comment: So then what's the data in `$sheet1_data` and `$sheet2_data`? Is it UTF-8 for all string values?

Comment: I'm using CakePHP, It's set to UTF-8. These vars came directly from database.

Comment: What does `get_file_location()` do? Are you sending the file directly to the browser, or saving it to server disk?

Comment: I'm saving on server. `get_file_location()` just assemble the path.

Comment: I feel like I'm trying to extract teeth here..... what version of PHPExcel are you running? Where did you download it from?

Comment: It wasn't me who downloaded. But the version is: `@version    1.8.0, 2014-03-02`

Comment: Well perhaps you'd consider updating to a more recent version: it's 8 months since 1.8.1 was released